# Transformed div doesn't register click Immediately

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

I'm flipping a div using css3 transform rotateY. It works fine except when I click the div while it is rotating. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Click Count:

Here is the HTML:

```
<flip-tile heading="Free Test" message="Take FREE TEST to earn embibium crystals!" status="'locked'" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div class="flip-holder locked" ng-class="status">
      <div class="front">
        <h3 class="title ng-binding">
          Free Test
        </h3>
        <img alt="Flip Button" class="flip-button" src="/assets/ts_metro_theme/flip-btn.png"><i class="lock-button fa fa-lock"></i><!-- ngIf: stats.rating=='champ' --><span class="count">2 of 3</span>
      </div>
      <!-- ngIf: status=='locked' --><div class="back ng-scope" ng-if="status=='locked'">
        <div class="buy-holder">
          <span class="ng-binding">Take FREE TEST to earn embibium crystals!</span><!-- ngIf: price -->
        </div>
        <img alt="flip-btn" class="flip-button" src="/assets/ts_metro_theme/flip-btn.png">
      </div><!-- end ngIf: status=='locked' -->
      <!-- ngIf: status!='locked' -->
    </div>
  </flip-tile>
```

The JS:

```
var i=0;
$('flip-tile').click(function(e){
    $('span.count').html(++i);
});
```

The CSS:

```
flip-tile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open sans', 'Quicksand', Helvetica;
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px; }

flip-tile .flip-holder,
flip-tile .front,
flip-tile .back {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit; }

flip-tile span.count {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none; }

flip-tile h3.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px; }

flip-tile .back p {
  margin: 10px; }

flip-tile .lock-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none; }

flip-tile .lock-button {
  display: none; }

flip-tile .locked .lock-button {
  display: inline-block; }

flip-tile .flip-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 23px;
  display: inline-block; }

flip-tile .imp-chapter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  color: #fbfdaa; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats {
  margin: 27px 10px; }

flip-tile .buy-holder {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 14px; }

flip-tile .buy-holder span {
  display: block; }

flip-tile .buy-holder button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .buy-holder button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444; }

flip-tile .front .champ-badge {
  width: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 6px; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats img {
  width: 17px; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats > div {
  margin: 4px 0; }

flip-tile .back .tile-stats span {
  width: 106px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right; }

flip-tile .flip-holder .front,
flip-tile .flip-holder .back {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .locked .front,
flip-tile .locked .back {
  background-color: #888;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .started .front,
flip-tile .started .back,
flip-tile .fresh .front,
flip-tile .fresh .back {
  background-color: #29b8eb;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .good .front,
flip-tile .good .back {
  background-color: #55a417;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .average .front,
flip-tile .average .back {
  background-color: #f29c21;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .bad .front,
flip-tile .bad .back {
  background-color: #f22133;
  color: #fff; }

flip-tile .fa-repeat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 156px;
  left: 10px; }

flip-tile .flip-holder {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  -ms-perspective: 100px;
  -o-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit; }

flip-tile:hover .flip-holder {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg); }

flip-tile .flip-holder {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative; }

flip-tile .front,
flip-tile .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }

flip-tile .front {
  z-index: 2; }

flip-tile .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg); }
```

And you can [run it live on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kptc2/).

Comment: for me (Chrome on Windows) it works pretty good...

Comment: Works like a charm in latest Safari and Chrome on Mac OS.

Comment: Nearly always works on Firefox.  Occasionally the click doesn't register, but I think it's because I'm moving the mouse fast enough that it is being processed as a drag or text-select event instead of a click event.  (In which case, it doesn't have anything to do with the rotation.)